# Guest Access to Samba server from two different machines

Tags: samba, samba4

I've setup `Samba 4.16.8` on a FreeBSD server with `guest` access, and found only one machine can connect at a time.

I can connect from the server using:

```
smbclient //172.16.23.24/worklist -U %
```

Then if I connect from a Windows machine (while still connected from the server) I get the error "The specified network name is no longer available", but if I disconnect from the server I can connect successfully from Windows.

The other way around is the same, if I initially connect from Windows, when I try to connect from the server I get the error "protocol negotiation failed: NT_STATUS_CONNECTION_DISCONNECTED" o "protocol negotiation failed: NT_STATUS_CONNECTION_RESET" (some times the former, some times the later).

Is this a limitation of `guest` access?.

This is my smb4.conf file:

```
[global]
log level          = 3
workgroup          = workgroup
netbios name       = smb
server string      = samba
server role        = standalone server
security           = user
usershare allow guests = yes
max smbd processes = 3
client min protocol = CORE
client max protocol = SMB3
socket options     = TCP_NODELAY IPTOS_LOWDELAY IPTOS_THROUGHPUT SO_KEEPALIVE SO_RCVBUF=65536 SO_SNDBUF=65536
aio read size      = 16384
aio write size     = 16384
strict locking     = no
strict sync        = no
map to guest       = Bad User

# DISABLE PRINTING
load printers           = no
disable spoolss         = yes
show add printer wizard = no

[worklist]
  path       = /home/worklist
  public     = yes
  read only  = no
  guest ok   = yes
  guest only   = yes
  browseable  = yes
  force user = worklist
  force group = worklist
```

**Edit:** the same happens if I want to connect from the server with `smbclient` from two terminals.

**Edit 2:** I created a Linux VM and configured Samba the same way and I've got the same results.

Comment: max smbd processes = 3 why do you limited this.?